# Init const C array of struct from multiple file

Tags: arrays, c, constants

Is there a way (a trick) to init a const array of struct from multiple files with GCC ?
I got several "modules" (.c/.h files) that can be build or not. I want each module be able to register itself into a global const array of struct without using RAM (it's an embedded project)
.

For instance I got a global dynamically allocated array of pointer to const struct span over several files but I want to remove it from RAM if I can

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to initialize something from multiple files, because that in turn suggests that something is weird with the program design. Also to complicate things, C doesn't regard `const` qualified variables as compile-time constant expressions, so you can't do `const int x = some_other_const;` at file scope.

One dirty old trick to initialize variables from multiple files is otherwise this:

```
const int array [] =
{
   #include "some_data.h"
   #include "more_data.h"
};

...

// some_data.h
1,2,3,

// more_data.h
4,5,6,
```

This is equivalent to:

```
const int array [] =
{
   1,2,3,
   4,5,6,
};
```

---

> For instance I got a global dynamically allocated array

You can't initialize dynamic arrays in compile-time anyway. Also the presence of them in an embedded system project is questionable at best. And in case of bare metal/RTOS it is complete nonsense, see [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Overall it seems that all your problems might originate from a muddy overall program design, so maybe take a step back and review the design before worry about details of the code itself.

Comment: Thank you to take time to respond to me. This is well know trick but not what I search. (For information our system support a lot of drivers, modules and platforms. It is heavly configurable at build time and run time. Memory allocation and pseudo introspection is crucial in this project. Generalities always have exceptions) Thank you very much

Comment: @rom1nux The common way to deal with such in embedded systems is to declare a big struct, allocate it in EEPROM/data flash, ensure that the struct matches the alignment requirments of that area, then dump all such data there. Now if you didn't something like ensuring that all items in memory are for example `uint32_t`, you can then have this struct inside a `union` with a `uint32_t[]` array. Then you get array notation or individual variable names flexibly, and you can change configurations that persist after power down.